# Files and folders are partially not displayed in Nautilus

Tags: files, usb-drive, hidden-files

I am facing a problem and I couldn't find any related post for that. I am regularly using an USB flash drive to move files from a Windows computer to my laptop which runs Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The problem here is that Nautilus doesn't show every file and folder. However when I use for instance the command ls/ll I see these files and folders. Also when I use the search bar in Nautilus, it will show me the files.

I had this problem for a longer time but since even folders are disappearing it is quite annoying and inconvenient for my daily work. I already tried to use the option "show hidden files" but the desired files stay hidden.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I figured out that there seems to be a problem with my permissions. When I tried to create a folder on my USB flash drive, it was not possible. I used the command `gksudo nautilus` to access nautilus with root. Here I was able to see every of my files and folders and also create new ones. I conclude that I have to change my permission options. How does it work?

Comment: Try F5 in your nautilus window with your usb stick to refresh the display. It worked for me.